# Is the flux through A the same as the flux through B?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

In the figure below, the amount of field lines through A is the same as the amount of field lines through B, but can you say the flux through A is the same as the flux through B as well?
[image]

Comment: Your figure/question has an ambiguity.  You have drawn arrows to represent the field.  But in your text you say field lines.  These are two different ways to represent the field.  If I go by your text, the answer is "yes".  If I go by your figure, the answer is "no".  (assuming the areas of A and B are the same, and that their orientation is the same)

Comment: The "amount of field lines" is *not* the same. You have drawn a field that is stronger at A, so in a field line representation there should be more field lines going through A.

Answer (score 2):

Electric flux is given by:

$$\Phi_E = \mathbf E\cdot \mathbf S = ES\cos\theta $$

Here, $S$ (vector area is same) while the strength of the electric field $E$ is more in $A$ (length of arrows). $\theta=0$ in both cases.

Hence flux is not same. $A > B$